# Как найти уязвимость на сайте под Битриксом?

Tags: битрикс, безопасность

Имеется сайт под Битриксом. С недавнего времени переписываются .htaccess и index.php, права доступа меняются на 444.

Восстанавливаем файлы из бекапа, права 600. Через какое-то время все повторяется.

Через консоль поставил всем файлам права 600, директориям 755.

Куда смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Начните с установки модуля [поиска троянов](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/bitrix.xscan/) и проверки системы, должно помочь.

Модуль **Поиск Троянов** поможет программистам найти трояны на сайте. Он сканирует весь сайт и сохраняет подозрительные файлы в список. Их можно посмотреть и поместить в карантин, где трояны не будут опасны. Разработчик 1С-Битрикс.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)